# issue with meta data in android studio

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi guys I've already try all the tutorials found here and in the developers site and I can't mannage to find the answer to my issue... ok I'm trying to make a simple app that render a map using gmaps... so I had already download the proper libreries... and in my build.gradle I compile them... so first let me show you my code...

this is my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.solmoviles.gpsmovil"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.solmoviles.gpsmovil.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
```

and here you have my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
}
```

and finaly here you have my logcat error

```
12-26 17:06:21.629  32452-32452/com.solmoviles.gpsmovil E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.solmoviles.gpsmovil/com.solmoviles.gpsmovil.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
        at maps.af.ay.a(Unknown Source)
        at maps.af.ay.a(Unknown Source)
        at maps.af.al.a(Unknown Source)
        at maps.af.be.a(Unknown Source)
        at maps.af.bd.a(Unknown Source)
        at cmj.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:900)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
```

so When I change the format of the meta data to the suggested one... it throws an error that says it was expecting a value of 4050300 and viceverse... PLEASE HELP ME...

after applying the suggestion Emmanuel provide me I have this

here you have the manifest as the way you suggested...

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.solmoviles.gpsmovil.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7Wb8"/>
    </application>
```

for security reasons I put the x on the api key... and the logcat is showing this

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.solmoviles.gpsmovil/com.solmoviles.gpsmovil.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.cE(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please read the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_the_api_key_to_your_application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have **both** meta-data's - play services version **AND** map API key, so you manifest would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.solmoviles.gpsmovil"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.solmoviles.gpsmovil.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="your_api_key"/>
</application>
```

Comment: thank you very much for the suggestion I will try it and I will inform you if that Worked.... regards....

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestion... @Pavel Dudka... I applied the suggestion and it finally worked... thanks for the suppot shown to the new developers....

Answer (score 0):

Like the `Exception` says, you are missing your API Key. You should have a structure like this on your `AndroidManifest.xml` just before the closing `</application>` tag:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="API_KEY"/>
```

Comment: thank you very much for the quick answer really appreciated... actually when I change the value of the meta data for the suggested one it throws an error that says it was expecting a value of 4050300... so none of those is helping actually... any other sugestion... regards...!!

Comment: Did you include the `meta-data` to your `AndroidManifest.xml` like I said above? Did you replace `API_KEY` with your actual key? Your stack trace is telling you that you are missing your API KEY.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer @Emmanuel... I will post what is showing my logcat...

Comment: I had already edit my post with the error I got with the answer suggested... regards